# Calling a generic method with the correct derived type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following scenario:

I have three classes, let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`. All they have in common is that they inherit from the same interface, `ISomeInterface` and that they are classes that are mapped to entities using Entity Framework.

I have a method that received a List of objects that implements this interface, but the objects themselves will be instances of `A`, `B` or `C`.

The method shell looks like this

```
public void MyMethod(List<ISomeInterface> entityList)
{
  foreach(var entity in entityList)
  {
    ProcessEntity(entity);
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is with the `ProcessEntity` method. This is a generic method, that needs to retrieve the table of matching elements from the database according to the type or entity, so it looks like this:

```
public void ProcessEntity<T>(T entity)
{
  using( var repository = new DbRepository())
  {
    var set = repository.Set<T>();
    ...
  }
}
```

The problem is that the line `var set = repository.Set<T>();` fails because `T` is `ISomeInterface` in this case, and not the actual type( `A`, `B` or `C`), so it gives an exception that is can't relate to the type given, which is understandable.

So my question is: How can i call ProcessEntity with the actual type of the object inside the list, and not the interfacetype that they implements.

Answer (score 14):

You can apply `dynamic` keyword when passing entity to ProcessEntity. In this case actual type of entity will be determined at runtime.

```
public void MyMethod(List<ISomeInterface> entityList)
{
  foreach(var entity in entityList)
  {
    dynamic obj = entity;
    ProcessEntity(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I change `ProcessEntity(obj);` to `ProcessEntity(obj as dynamic);`, and that worked out just fine. A use for dynamic I didn't know about. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen yep, I like this run-time typification a lot

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do a visitor-like trick and use the following workaround:

1. Define a method `Process(EntityProcessor ep)` in `ISomeInterface`
2. Implement it in `A` just as `ep.ProcessEntity<A>(this)` (and the same way in `B` and `C`)
3. Instead of `ProcessEntity(entity)` in your loop, just call `entity.Process(this)`.

(the method names are perhaps not cleanest, but you should get the idea)

Comment: This would work, but lazyberezovsky's answer is much cleaner for me since that means I don't have to put more logic into A, B and C (and there is acutally like 20 of these types, not 3 ;) )

Comment: @Øyvind: well, my solution requires more work, but it checks the existence of the needed method at compile time. As well, it might be slightly faster.

Comment: I see your point, but using dynamic you don't have a needed method at all, and I would prefer that the classes A, B and C don't have any knowledge about this functionality as well. It also means that I don't have to remember to put this extra functionality for new classes created that are supposed to follow the same pattern.

Comment: @Øyvind: the using of `dynamic` makes the code more compact, at a price of sacrificing some type safety. As always in software development, it's a trade-off. For the new classes, you won't be able to forget implementing the needed member, as it's required by interface.

Comment: Totally agreed there. It's a trade-off like most everything else. Not sure what you are referring to by the member of the interface tho. The implementation I ended up with uses no member of the interface, it just checks that the class implements the interface, but the actual interface implementation is used for something else, and not for this specific functionality.

Comment: @Øyvind: at my example, a new function is added to `ISomeInterface` (which is indeed a kind of visitor pattern support). This way every `entity` has to implement it, as it implements `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I am avoiding by using dynamic. So, the tradeoff in this case is losing some type safety (and I'm ok with it in this case, since it's just within that one method) for keeping the entityclasses cleaner by not forcing some interface method on them that must be implemented by all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection to get the generic method definition and then call it, eg:

```
var method = typeof(ClassContainingProcessEntity)
    .GetMethod(ProcessEntity)
    .MakeGenericMethod(entity.GetType);
method.Invoke(this, entity);
```

You could cache the method by type, and you could compile it at runtime using some kind of delegate factory if performance is critical.

Alternatively you could use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Yup, both should work, and I was thinking of going the reflection route if I got no better answer in here. Seems like dynamic fixes this a lot cleaner though. Thanks for your input :)